DirectoryEntry / DirectorySearcher is not working on Windows11 24H2
The below code (it is just an example) works well on Windows 10 on computers joined or not to the domain. It works well on previous version of Windows 11 24H2 on domained or not domained computers. However it fails running on Windows 11 24H2 on not domained computers (it runs wells on domained computers). I need this code running on W11 24H2 non domained computers (as I said, this work well on non domained computer running Windows versions previous to W11 24H2). How can I make this happen? Any clue?.
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain /*+ "ou=" + deptou + ";dc=xxxxxx;dc=ca"*/, user, password);
DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
mySearcher.Filter = "(memberOf=CN=GP_PCJoinApp" + ",OU=info_serv,DC=" + domain + ",DC=ca)"; 
        
foreach (SearchResult temp in mySearcher.FindAll())
{
    MessageBox.Show(temp.Properties["samaccountname"][0].ToString());
} 


What error are you getting? I wouldn't expect it to work at all on any non-domained machine: they don't know how to find the LDAP server, also LDAPS (secured) is usually required these days. Is user a proper username of the form user@yourdomain.com

How do you expect code that has a literal variable called domain to work on a machine that isn't on a domain?

Charlieface and mjwills, thank you very much for pointing out my mistake. Sorry for this question. I will post a quick fix. Thanks!!
